# SQL Why count CHAR in MySQLWorkbanch between Server was different

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query the messages from the server to send out with line notify but I already using auto space as my script and showing well in Workbench but when bringing this code into the server the result not same as testing by Workbench so Can anyone advise me on this?

Background :
Workbench using the same database with the server
I trying to change the type from Char to NChar but the system can't change

**Query from Server**

[image]

**Query by Workbench**

[image]

**Code**

```
SELECT 
    MAX(T1.ID) as ID,
    T1.site_id as user_id,
    tank_product,
    volume,
    ullage,
    water_volume,
    site.sfl_limit,
    timestamp,
    concat('\n', 'Inventory Report') as Title,
    concat ((site.name),'\n','Inventory Report ','\n',current_date(),' ',current_time(),'\n\n','Tank ',space(2),'Product Name',space(4),'Volume',space(2),
    site.sfl_limit*'100','%',' Ullage',space(2),'Water',space(6),'Times',
    group_concat(concat(
                    '\n',

                    space(1),IF (length(format(tank.number,0)) > 2,format(tank.number,0),concat(format(tank.number,0),space(2 - length(format(tank.number,0))))), space(4),
                    IF (length(tank.name) > 17,tank.name,concat(tank.name,space(17 - length(tank.name)))),
                    IF (length(format(T1.volume,0)) > 8,format(T1.volume,0),concat(format(T1.volume,0),space(8 - length(format(T1.volume,0))))),space(1), 
                    IF (length(IF(format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0)>0,format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0),0)) > 8,
                            IF(format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0)>0,format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0),0),
                                concat(IF(format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0)>0,format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0),0),
                                    space(8 - length(IF(format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0)>0,format (((tank.max_or_lable * site.sfl_limit) - T1.volume),0),0))))),space(3),
                    IF (length(format(T1.water,0)) > 8,format(T1.water,0),concat(format(T1.water,0),space(8 - length(format(T1.water,0))))), 
                    timestamp
                    )

                    order by tank_product))
                    as Message



                    FROM inventory as T1

                    INNER JOIN  tank on T1.site_id = tank.site_id and T1.tank_product = tank.number 
                    INNER JOIN site on T1.site_id = site.ID 
                    INNER JOIN user_information ON user_information.ID = site.ID 
                    where T1.site_id = 3 and T1.tank_product in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) order by tank_product and line_access_token IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure your database is MySQL?  Can you post a _minimal_ question?  Your query is very large, and most of it might not be helping.

Comment: I'm not even clear on what you're actually asking here?

Comment: You can see as picture on query by Workbanch and query from server in same code but the result different. Thansk.

Comment: If you are executing the same query but get different results - probably this is not the same database. Perhaps the first database lives on your server and the second one lives on your development PC.

Comment: Both are using same data base is server. Thanks.